# Condition for an unbounded continuous second derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm trying to show the following:

Assume we have a function $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
f'' \text{ is continuous on } [0, \infty) \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \text{ exists} \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) \text{ does not exist.}
\end{align}

Show that $f''$ is unbounded.

My approach is that I want to proceed by contradiction and consider the first above assumptions on a function $f$ such that $|f''(x)| \leq M$ for some $M$.  I am not sure really where to go from here.